# In the proof of Hadamard's formula for power series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

This is the relevant theorem in Stein and Shakarchi's *Complex Analysis* and part of its proof:
[image]

My question is, how do we know we can find $\epsilon$ small enough that $(L+\epsilon{)}|z|=r<1$? What if $z=1$ and $0<R<1$? Then $L=1/R>1$, so how can its product with $z$ be less than 1?

Comment: There's an assumption that $\lvert z\rvert < R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|z|<R$, then $L|z|<1$ by the the definition of $L$. Thus one can find $\epsilon'>0$ small enough so that
$$
L|z|+\epsilon'<1.
$$
Now let $\epsilon$ be such that 
$$
\epsilon |z|=\epsilon'.
$$